# File System Entries Browser Dialog c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, dialog

I'm usin Windows.Forms aplication and I can get files or directory from my user using `OpenFileDialog` or `FolderBrowserDialog`. But I need get both in a unique dialog. I Try use `OpenFileDialog` with `.multselect = true` and select files and folders, but in code when I acess `OpenFileDialog.FileNames` this property returns only a file names, never a selected directory.

Exists a static method in `System.IO.Directory` call `GetFileSystemEntries` that do exactly I want. But I need a Dialog that do it.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: There isn't such component in the standard controls shipped with Visual Studio. Also your MultiSelect doens't allows to select files in different directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is not possible to get folder and files with inly a single
>   dialog().

*According to microsoft's documentation about c# You have to use    different dialog to select folder and files*

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
string baseFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(strToFile).ToString();
```

This will give you the folder name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

or use FileInfo!

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strToFile);
string fileFolder = fi.DirectoryName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string[] files = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

                if (files != null && files.Length > 0)
                {
                    // returns the root directory
                    string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(files[0]);

                    // Obtain the file system entries in the directory path.
                    string[] directoryEntries =
                        System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(folder); 
                }
            }

        }
```